# templated comparison function in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following compare function that I pass to the `std::sort` algorithm to sort a vector of objects:

```
template <typename PointT>
bool myCompareLines (A<PointT>::model_struct model_a, A<PointT>::model_struct model_b) {
    return (/* some comparison code*/);
}
```

The compare function is declared outside the class and I am calling it like this:

```
template <typename PointT>
class B {
    [...]
    std::sort(lines.begin().lines.end(),::myCompareLines);
    [...]
}
```

When I compile I get the error: `template declaration of 'bool myCompareLines'`

Inside `class A` I declare `class B` as a friend class so that `class B` can 
access the the private type `model_struct`.  What am I missing?

Comment: `myCompareLines` is a template, not a function.

Comment: Thanks for all those who answered,  I was missing the typename keyword in signature of myCompareLines.  so it should be:

Comment: bool myCompareLines(typename A<PointT>::model_struct model_a, typename A<PointT>::model_struct model_b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the typename keyword in my CompareLines signature.

This fixes it:

```
bool myCompareLines (typename A<PointT>::model_struct model_a, typename B<PointT>::model_struct model_b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Though hideous, is *this* what you're looking for? Note: Compiles does not equate to good. Even if this works for you I would suggest an alternate way of declaring your hierarchy.

```
template<class PointT>
class A
{
public:
    A() {};

    struct model_stuct
    {
        // need something to use in comparison, so i just threw this in.
        int value;
    };
};

// comparitor
template<class PointT>
bool compareLines(
    const typename A<PointT>::model_stuct& left,
    const typename A<PointT>::model_stuct& right)
{
    return left.value < right.value;
}

template<class PointT>
class B
{
public:
    B() : lines() {};

    void sort()
    {
        std::sort(lines.begin(), lines.end(), compareLines<PointT>);
    }

    std::vector<typename A<PointT>::model_stuct> lines;
};


// main entrypoint
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // this does nothing, but demonstrate that it can compile and
    //  sort() doesn't puke. 
    B<int> bInt;
    bInt.sort();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for having the only answer that addresses the missing `typename`s. [Online demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/07d72908e0f017fe5c8c3b55c8a2a9f9)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you just do:

```
template <typename PointT>
class B {
    [...]
    std::sort(lines.begin(), lines.end(), ::myCompareLines<PointT>);
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler cannot deduce template param `PointT` from inner class `A<PointT>::model_struct`.

It cannot because many specialization of `A<PointT>` can have identical `model_struct` - like:

```
template <class PointT>
class A {
public:
  typedef int model_struct;
};
```

with this example:

```
   int a;
   bool res = compareLines(a,a);
```

Define `model_struct` as top level template.